# functions of javascript "return"

Tags: javascript, html, variables, return

In JavaScript, can return be used to "kill" a variable so to speak (as in, stop it from functioning past that point throughout the code)? I am working on this piece of code and I want the variable "msg" to stop working if its value is empty to avoid the alert box from popping up. Is this correct, or would the alert still pop up?

```
if(msg==””){
return result; 
}

{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I actually am not able to test the code at the minute because I only have fragments, but I was wondering if anyone could answer from pure theory

Comment: Why not use return false?

Answer (score 1):

`return` is used to allow functions to hand back control, it can not be used outside of a function. I think what you are looking for is `else`

```
if(msg==""){
 // do something
} else {
  alert(msg);
}
```

If you want to "kill" a variable, all you can do is `delete VARIABLE_NAME` which will make it `undefined`

Comment: thank you! if i were to run the code as is, do you know what would happen?

Comment: well, since we did not define msg, it would do nothing. If we added `msg="hello world"` to the top, it would alert "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a simple condition on your `alert` ?

```
 if(msg!="")
    alert(msg)

 return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to happen.

Do you want the code within your function to continue executing if `msg` is ""?

If so, then use else:

```
if (msg) {
   alert(msg);
} else {
   //continue on in function while msg is ""
}
```

Or do you want to exit out of the function altogether?  If so:

```
if (!msg) {
   return;
}

alert(msg);

// continue on in function while msg is NOT ""
```